# looking for a way to wrap my fields with rails form helpers (fields_for?)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, fields-for

I'm looking for a way to write a form that generates an array as one of its params. I have an array of hashes:

```
@sub_commands = [
      { type: "install_app", appName: "LOCATOR", appVersion: '1.0' },
      { type: "install_app", appName: "recorder", appVersion: '1.4' }
    ]
```

and I want this array as on of my params, for example: `params["command"]["sub_commands][0] == [{"type"=>"install_app", "appName"=>"LOCATOR", "appVersion"=>"1.0" }]`

I could achieve this with the following code in my view:

```
<% @sub_commands.each do |sub_commnad| %>
  <%= select_tag "command[sub_commands[][type]]", options_for_select(["install_app", "load_dll"]) %>
  <%= text_field_tag "command[sub_commands[][appName]]", sub_commnad[:appName] %>
  <%= text_field_tag "command[sub_commands[][appVersion]]", sub_commnad[:appVersion] %>
<br />
```

But I guess there are more "clean" ways to do it with rails helpers. Can you try to rewrite my view code?

Comment: Look this http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for if help

Comment: I read the dock, the answer was not there